# How to use variable names for array parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked before but I am really confused as how to apply it in my particular instance.

I am trying to use a variable instead of productId1 in my array parameter, but I am not sure on how to do

```
var obj = {};
obj.push(something)
```

with this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
$BV.ui( 'rr', 'inline_ratings', {
             productIds : {
                  'productId1': { 
                  url : '/Dummy URL here'
                }
             },
```

Comment: What you have is a **JavaScript object** (literal), which has nothing to do with JSON (or arrays).

Comment: Gotcha! I was searching JSON thats probably why I was getting wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variable keys in object literals.  You have to create the object first and then use `obj[key]` syntax to fill in the object, e.g:

```
var obj = { };
obj[productId1] = { url: '/Dummy UR here' }
$BV.ui('rr', 'inline_ratings', obj);
```

Comment: so should I create a productIds object and fill it with productId1 as the key ?